# Does the position of the fuse affect whether the bulb or the fuse would blow first?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity

If I connect a fuse and a bulb in series with:

1. fuse to the live and bulb to the neutral
2. fuse to the neutral and bulb to the live

During an overloading would this cause:

1. the fuse to blow and successfully protecting the bulb in the first case
2. the bulb to get damaged before blowing the fuse in the second case

**or**

3. just the fuse blowing, not damaging the bulb in both cases

Please answer in the cases of both DC and AC.

Comment: Protecting the bulb against what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In either case the bulb will be protected by the blowing of the fuse, further this also works when the current is AC or DC.

The reason for this is because fuses are calibrated to blow at a rated amperage, where the fuse is in the series circuit does not change the current flowing through it, therefore it protects the circuit in either location.